# Can passing a Nullpointer to fwrite cause problems

Tags: c++, fwrite

I've recently written some code where, under certain circumstances, a Nullpointer might be passed to `fwrite`.

Although it worked on windows I've wondered if it might cause problems on other platforms or if there's anything that prevents that.

---

How I produced such a mess ;) :

```
std::vector<unsigned char> bytes;

// ...
// bytes could be filled but may be empty.

const char* bytesToWrite = (const char*) bytes.data();   // .data() will return NULL if empty
unsigned long count = bytes.size();

if (count == fwrite(bytesToWrite, 1, count, handle)) //...
```

Comment: Please fix tags. `std::vector` cannot be C.

Comment: No, passing `NULL` to `fwrite` is UB. Just don't do it. But as you also passed a count of 0 you might get away with it on one platform, but maybe not on another one. Just test if the size is 0, and skip the `fwrite`.

Comment: Usefull docs : https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/FIO18-C.+Never+expect+fwrite%28%29+to+terminate+the+writing+process+at+a+null+character

Comment: @user694733 last time I tagged a question about fopen/fread/fwrite with c++ i got severely downvoted because of that...

Comment: That is unfortunate. Some people might vote based on their personal opinion on the code, which *in my opinion*, is incorrect. Anyway, since this code clearly won't compile as C, and fwrite is also part of C++, then C++ is the correct tag to use.

Comment: @user694733 Yeah thats right! I'll try to get that right next time ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Microsoft [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9t88zwz.aspx):

> fwrite returns the number of full items actually written, which may be less than count if an error occurs. Also, if an error occurs, the file-position indicator cannot be determined. **If either stream or buffer is a null pointer, or if an odd number of bytes to be written is specified in Unicode mode, the function invokes the invalid parameter handler**, as described in Parameter Validation. If execution is allowed to continue, this function sets errno to EINVAL and returns 0.

So it works in Windows (well, you get an explicit error instead of a loud crash but it's still not very useful). But there's no trace of this case in Unix/Linux so just don't rely on it. Always test beforehand:

```
if (buffer != NULL) { fwrite(buffer, ...
```

or use `assert(buffer != NULL)` to turn undefined behaviour into *defined behaviour*.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the documentation link! Well I guess I just have to check for NULL in this case!

Answer (score 1):

There is just a small performance penalty if you add an additional if to check for the `NULL` ptr.

Passing `NULL` to `fwrite` is undefined behavior and it will probably cause a segmentation fault in the best case.

Change your code to this:

```
const char* bytesToWrite = (const char*) bytes.data();   
if(bytesToWrite != NULL)
{
    unsigned long count = bytes.size();

    if (count == fwrite(bytesToWrite, 1, count, handle)) //...
}
```